# Can both the following loop be parallelized?

Tags: parallel-processing

```
do i=2, n-1
   y(i) = y(i+1)
end do

do i=2, n-1
   y(i) = y(i+1) - y(i-1)
end do
```

Hi, I'm wondering if both of these loop can be parallelized? It seems that the `y(i+1)` part makes it not possible. Because it depends on value that's not generated yet.

Comment: Not any specific language, just in general. If you need to know then it is OpenMP, and MPI

Answer (score 0):

If y is an array (it LOOKS like a function, but then you'd be assigning to a function call), then the y(i+1) part already exists, although it is still problematic for parallelizing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

You just need to write it in such a way that each parallel task doesn't "step on" any other task's memory.

In the second case, that would be a tricky, but I'm certain it's possible with enough thought.

Comment: In the case of OpenMP, i would only specify that the loop should be parallelized. Do you mean I would need to modify the inner structure of the loop?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP, sorry. All my threading work is done with libdispatch. Perhaps you'd get clearer examples if you actually showed what you're trying to do, instead of a contrived example.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert How would you parallelize the second loop? You need to know the final, computed value of A(i-1) before you compute A(i).

Comment: @Patrick87 off the top of my head, perhaps one option would be to have one task fetch i+1 while a second task fetches i-1, a third thread does the actual math, and a fourth thread writes the result out. That's 4 parallel tasks. In this case, I'm not sure if it would create any performance improvement. Obviously you would need some code to ensure (i-1) isn't being fetched until the other thread has applied the new value.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, parallelization is only possible if you have a secondary storage area. For maximum parallelism, you will need a completely separate array:

```
for all i in [2, n-2] in parallel do
   y'(i) = y(i+1)
end do
```

If you only want to use two parallel execution units, you will need storage for one element of the array:

```
e = y(n/2)
for all i in [0, 1] in parallel do
   for j in [1, n/2 - 1] do
      y(i*n/2 + j) = (y(i*n/2 + j)
   end do
end do
y(n/2 - 1) = e
```

You need this to avoid the race condition on the last element of the first half and the first element of the second half. In fact, there is a direct relationship between the amount of additional storage you need and the factor by which you parallelize the code.

The second loop cannot be parallelized, since you must have computed y(i-1) to compute y(i). No way. This isn't a problem for the first loop since all values which are eventually read are guaranteed to have the correct value in them before the loop starts. Not so in the second!

For what it's worth, these loops can be combined, if they are meant to be executed sequentially. That would be faster than parallelizing the first and leaving the second alone.

Comment: For second loop... the right hand side can be restated using only values from original array (oy) to compute new array (ny). Compute oy(3)-oy(1) and you can then computed new ny(2). Compute oy(4)-oy(3)+oy(1) and you can compute new ny(3). Then oy(5)-oy(4) plus the first value we calculated to get ny(4), oy(6)-oy(5) plus the second vlaue we calculated to get ny(5), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you have what's called a "loop carried dependency"

```
do i=2, n-1    
    y(i) = y(i+1) - y(i-1) 
end do
```

The calculation for y(i) depends on y(i +/- 1) because in a parallel loop you cannot guarentee the order in which i will be executed y(i+1) may have already been updated to its new value before y(i) is calculated. Worse still y(i+1) may be in the process of being updated on one thread while another thread attempts to read what might be a corrupt value (because its data is only half way through being updated. In either case you'll get incorrect answers.

The best solution here is to have a readonly and writable array

```
do i=2, n-1    
    yNew(i) = yOld(i+1) - yOld(i-1) 
end do
swap(yOld, yNew)
```

Now your problem goes away because array y is not updated by the parallel loop. If your language supports pointers you can easily swap the new/old arrays by maintaining pointers to them and simply swapping the pointers. The only additional overhead is that you need to keep an additional copy of your data as a readonly copy for the loop to refer to.